# PDO Select query using array of OR

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have an array of objects:

```
$arr = array('10', '12');
```

and i am running this query using PDO:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * from table WHERE user_sequence = :user_sequence");
```

i want to be able to have the query say `WHERE user_sequence = :item1 OR user_sequence = :item2`

`item1, item2` etc being the objects from the array

how can i do this using PDO?

usually in MySQL, i would do:

```
$sql="SELECT * from table WHERE ";
foreach($array as $a) {
    $sql.="col = '".$a."' OR ";
}
```

but im not sure how to copy this theory in a PDO query

Comment: You would do the query as you have written it `WHERE (user_sequence = :item1 OR user_sequence = :item2)` and bind your variable accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
$values = [ 'first value', 'second value', 'third value' ];

$conds = array_map(function() {
    return "user_sequence = ?";
}, $values);

$sql = "SELECT * from table WHERE " . implode(" OR ", $conds);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($values);
```

Comment: just tried this, im getting an error (Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::execute())

Comment: @charlie Sorry, I had a small mistake.

Comment: @charlie You should consider accepting more of the answers to your questions. It shows future visitors to the site which ones worked for you and also gives reputation points to both you and the person whose answer you accept.